# SMTP exception - SMTPAddressFailedException

Tags: smtp, smtpclient

Getting the below exception when using SMTP to send mail for particular user.

Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 abc@t.com... User unknown.

here in this exception above , abc@t.com is valid user but still SMTP causing some issue.

what might be the issue and root cause for this problem?

Tried restarting the SMTP but still failing